# How can I start a process in powershell and redirect its output without waiting for the whole process tree?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to launch a process and send its output to tee, but the process launches a dangling child process (adb server). Start-process or just piping it in powershell end up waiting for the whole process tree, so they never terminate.

`myprocess.exe | tee-object -file logfile.txt`

This works, but hangs forever in powershell since myprocess exits but its child doesn't.

`$child = start-process myprocess --passthru; wait-process $child`

This waiting behavior is fine, but then how do I send the output to tee-object?

`start-process myprocess.exe -WaitForOnlyParent | tee-object ...`

This would be perfect, but it doesn't exist.